# Testing an Assignment class

Tags: java

This is my first programming assignment. This is a second file that is intended to test the setters and getters (both constructors and no-argument constructors). How can I clean this up (curly brackets or combining similar methods/lines) to make it look more legible and understandable? I'll be adding comments later.

```
/**
   A class to test the Assignment class
*/
public class AssignmentTester
{ 
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Assignment getterTest = new Assignment();

         System.out.println("TESTING NO-ARGUMENT CONSTRUCTOR AND GETTERS");
         System.out.println("=========================================== \n");

         System.out.println(getterTest.getTitle());
         System.out.println("Expected: Assignment 1 \n"); 

         System.out.println(getterTest.getDueDate());
         System.out.println("Expected: 01/01/2019 \n"); 

         System.out.println(getterTest.getMaxPoints());
         System.out.println("Expected: 10.0 \n"); 

         System.out.println(getterTest.getCategory());
         System.out.println("Expected: Programming Assignments \n \n"); 

      System.out.println("Testing Setters");
      System.out.println("=============== \n");   

      Assignment setterTest = new Assignment();

         setterTest.setTitle("CodeLab 12");  
         System.out.println(setterTest.getTitle());
         System.out.println("Expected: CodeLab 1 \n");  

         setterTest.setDueDate("02/09/2019");
         System.out.println(setterTest.getDueDate());
         System.out.println("Expected: 02/09/2019 \n");

         setterTest.setMaxPoints(5.0);
         System.out.println(setterTest.getDueDate());
         System.out.println("expected: 5.0 \n");

         setterTest.setCategory("CodeLab, Quizzes, ICE");
         System.out.println(setterTest.getCategory());
         System.out.println("Expected: CodeLab, Quizzes, ICE \n \n");

   }   

}
```

If interested, here is my first Java file. Please let me know if I can improve on this in any way:

```
/**
   Describes an assignment's title, due date, total points value, and category
*/

public class Assignment 
{
   private String title;     //Title of assignment
   private String dueDate;   //Due date of assignment
   private double maxPoints; //Max points of assignment
   private String category;  //Category of assignment

   /**
      Initialize instance variables for assignment project (no argument-constructor)
   */ 
   public Assignment()  
   {
      title = "Assignment 1";
      dueDate = "01/01/2019";
      maxPoints = 10.0;
      category = "Programming Assignments";
   }

   /** 
      Initialize instance variables for the assignment project (argument constructor)
      @param t title of assignment
      @param d due date of assignment
      @param m max points for the assignment
      @param c category of assignment
   */ 
   public Assignment(String t, String d, double m,String c)   
   {
      title = t; 
      dueDate = d;
      maxPoints = m;
      category = c;
   }

   /**
      Sets the value of title
      @param t title of assignment
   */
   public void setTitle(String t)
   {
      title = t; 
   }

   /**
      Sets the value of dueDate
      @param d due date of assignment
   */
   public void setDueDate(String d)
   {
      dueDate = d;
   }

   /**
      Sets value of maxPoints
      @param m max points of assignment
   */
   public void setMaxPoints(double m)
   {
      maxPoints = m;
   }

   /**
      Sets the value of category
      @param c category of assignment
   */
   public void setCategory(String c)
   {
      category = c;
   }

   /**
      Returns the value of title
      @return title of assingment
   */
   public String getTitle()
   {
      return title;
   }

   /**
      Returns the value of dueDate
      @return due date of assignment
   */
   public String getDueDate()
   {
      return dueDate;
   }

   /**
      Returns the value of maxPoints
      @return max points of assignment
   */
   public double getMaxPoints()
   {
      return maxPoints;
   }

   /**
      Returns the value of category
      @return category of assingmen
   */
   public String getCategory()
   {
      return category;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend evening out your indentation. A lot of seasoned programmers have developed an intuitive sense about what code is and isn't a problem. Things like haphazard indentation can trigger that sense, and so we look at your code and feel like there has to be a problem somewhere. This can be an extra factor if someone is grading your work by hand and trying to rush. If they want to average under a minute per student, they may not take the time to realize it was a false alarm - and they may not care. They may be trying to keep it under 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The go to unit testing framework in Java is [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/) and all major IDE tools have builtin support for writing test cases.

However, for very simple purposes and learning purpose, Java JDK has the [`assert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) keyword that can be used to test assumptions and also do unit tests.  in both cases (JUnit and `assert`) the rule is that failed tests throw exceptions that may have customized messages.

an example of usage of `assert`:

```
assert getterTest.getTitle().equals("Assignment 1") : "wrong title default value"
```

note that assertions need to be explicitly enabled at runtime:

> Enabling and Disabling Assertions By default, assertions are disabled
>   at runtime. Two command-line switches allow you to selectively enable
>   or disable assertions.
>
> To enable assertions at various granularities, use the
>   -enableassertions, or -ea, switch. To disable assertions at various granularities, use the -disableassertions, or -da, switch.

Comment: Java assertions are not a testing framework, and using them in that fashion is decidedly non-standard and will confuse other developers. The intent of the assertion framework is to provide weak Design-By-Contract support. You can read more about assertions  at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

Comment: JUnit uses the same terminology (assertions) and throws the exact same exception when a test fails (`AssertionError`) and it is decidedly *the* unit testing framework in the Java world, while java assertions are not? fooled me